# Icons and images inside the CSS are not showing on HTML

Tags: html, css

This is my `CSS`. I have used the correct path. When I load the page on Safari, I see an orange square (the reference image is an orange logo). On Chrome, I see nothing.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: 100;
        
}

ul li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

ul li::before {
    content: ""; 
    background: url(images/icons/heartgoldicon.ico);  
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}
```

Edit: I just tried to use a link instead, and it shows. I have no idea what's wrong with the images in the icons folder, but nothing inside that works. I have images inside 'images', and that works fine.

Comment: I don't think the `.ico` format is supposed to be used inside a web page. I only ever see it being used for favicons.

Comment: I'm not sure `.ico` files are able to be rendered? They're just used for favicons. Try using a regular file type, like `.jpg` or `.png`... Edit: If its only icons that aren't rendering, then there you go. `.ico` files are old and only used by Operating Systems.

Comment: I just tried your code in Brackets with a sample ico file and it works just fine.

Comment: If one of the solutions given here has answered your question, you should mark that answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few potential issues that may be causing your icon not to show up:

1. The use of the `.ico` format
2. Using a relative path to your icon

The `.ico` format may not work on all browsers and you should use a more known format like `png` or `jpg`. It is generally used for `favicons`, not for icons. Some browsers may display them while some may not.

Your current path to the image is a relative path, so where your `css` file is located will matter to the search. `background: url(images/icons/heartgoldicon.ico)` will search that from the current folder that your `css` file is located. You can use an absolute path by starting with a `/`, and then it will always look for the file from the root folder. Example use `background: url("/images/icons/your-icon.png")`,